# Let $H$ be the set of matrices in $O_n(\mathbb{R})$ whose matrix entries are integers.

Tags: group-theory, orthogonal-matrices

1. Prove that $H$ is equal to the set of all $n\times n$ matrices $A=(a_{ij})$ with integer coefficients such that $\vert a_{ij}\vert=0$ or $1$ for all $i,j$ and each row and column of $A$ has one non-zero entry.

So every row and column of $A$ has exactly one non-zero entry, which is either $1$ or $-1$. I don't really know where to start with this, and presumably the next part of the question is also link with this.

2. Prove that the order of $H$ is $2^nn!$.

Comment: Remember that orthogonal matrices represent isometries, and preserve orthonormal bases. The column vectors are the respective images of the standard basis vectors. So, you want an orthonormal basis with integer coefficients; there aren't many of those!

Comment: Ok, so I know that orthogonal matrices represent reflection or rotation, but what do you mean they preserve orthonormal bases?

Comment: If you have an orthonormal basis of column vectors $(e_1, \ldots, e_n)$ and $M \in H$, then $(Me_1, \ldots, Me_n)$ is another orthonormal basis of column vectors. Have you done anything with orthonormal bases yet?

Comment: Not much. I know that orthonormal basis vectors should have length 1 and should be linearly independent.

Comment: It's more than linear independence: they should be orthogonal, as in their pairwise dot products should all be $0$ (except when dot producting a vector with itself).

Comment: Yes, that's right. So what does preserving orthonormal basis mean?

Comment: It means what I said in the third comment. Although, it would suffice just to note that the columns of an orthogonal matrix are orthonormal.

Comment: As I said in the first comment, orthonormal bases with integer coordinates are very rare!

Comment: I understand now. thank you